# Orbeon - Loading form in Form Runner with previosuly entered data

Tags: orbeon

I have created a form using Orbeon Form builder and saved data to orbeon_form_data table. I want to know if there is a way to load that same form in the web browser with the previously entered data pre-populated in relevant form fields using form runner? Need help please...

Comment: I am not sure to follow you: how does the "previously entered" data relate to the current form you created with Form Builder? Was it entered in another form also created with Form Builder?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is: I have created a from from Form Builder and published it. End user can add data and save to orbeon db. When end user wants to edit those data is there a way to load the same form instance? The end user can access form builder only, for example a URL like this `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/MonashHealth/COI_Procurement/new`

Comment: Also I refereed the `http://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner.html#initial-instance` page, I want to know where I should add the `<form method="post" action="/path/to/new"><input type="hidden" name="fr-form-data" value="Base64-encoded XML"/>
</form>`                                                                                        is it in the xforms code I access using the Form settings tool?               And also if I'm using a web service, could you please tell me how to set values to form fields using the data retrieved from service? Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: To edit data their previously entered, or more generally to which they have access to, they can just go to `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/MonashHealth/COI_Procurement/summary`. From there they can select which form data they want to edit. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: yes, got it done, also can use the form with <documentid>/edit mode to get the same form with values for editing. Thank you!

Comment: Yes; and the the summary page just provides you link to the documents you can view or edit, but if you know the document id, you can produce the link bypassing the summary page.

Comment: And I've posted an expanded version of my above comment as answer below, so people don't have to do through all the comments to find the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation @avernet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit data their previously entered, or more generally to which they have access to, they can just go to `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/MonashHealth/COI_Procurement/summary`. This is often referred to as the [summary page](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/summary-page.html) for your form. From there users can open all the forms they have access to, the access depending in part on [permissions](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/access-control/deployed-forms.html) you defined for that form in Form Builder.